# Why would you use 0 > 0 in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was going through some of StackOverflow's client side code and I ran across this block of JavaScript in the source-code of [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask):

```
if ($answerCheckbox.is(':checked') || 0 > 0) {
     $answerCheckbox.attr('checked', true);
     $('#question-only-section').hide();
     StackExchange.using("editor", function () {
          setTimeout(function () { showAnswerSection(true) }, 2);
     });
}
```

Why wouldn't you use `false` instead?

Comment: No reason at all, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Why would you use false either?

Comment: Isn't this code generated ? What's the file ?

Comment: My guess is that the numbers in the `0 > 0` are generated by a server-side script.

Comment: You might want to ask this over on meta.

Comment: Because it looks like a face!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're assuming the code is all natively written Javascript. It isn't uncommon to see some server-generated script which references elements via some programmatic identifier which resolves like this at runtime, which admittedly looks a little peculiar.

Answer (score 6):

It is generated code (not in a .js) file so obviously one of those two values is not always 0 but a server-side variable.

Answer (score 6):

There is no reason for it... but until you know the server side code, you can't know for sure.

Let's say (PHP) you had a variable `$x=1` and could also be `$x=0` depending on the scenario.

```
if ($answerCheckbox.is(':checked') || <?php echo $x;?> > 0) {
```

That code makes perfect sense....

Answer (score 4):

Because that line probably comes from php, like so:

```
if ($answerCheckbox.is(':checked') || <?php echo $tot; ?> > 0) {
```

I know because in some situations I had to write code like that.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: What *do* you use?  *ASP*? Ha!

Comment: *I* am not SE - but SE uses ASP.NET (C#)

Comment: Didn't know what StackOverflow uses, just that I've seen the same code from my experience in PHP.